# Auth deny not working in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I'm using CakePHP 3.4.

I want to restrict some action to non-admin users.

This is what I tried in my controller

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    if (!$this->Auth->user('super_admin')) {
        $this->Auth->deny(['index', 'view', 'add', 'delete']);
    }
}
```

But even non-admin user is able to access denied locations. I tried printing debug in if statement and it is working, means if statement is being called but `deny()` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need `parent::beforeFilter($event);` if this is not the app.php file ?

Or you could try this :

```
if((!$this->Auth->user('super_admin')) && ($this->request->action === 'index')){
            //Your redirect and flash
        }
```

Comment: I added `parent:: beforeFilter($event);` but it doesn't work. I'm already using that hard way in my code.

Comment: @AnujTBE  Did you call your AuthComponent in your controller ?
try first to debug this :
`debug($this->Auth->user); die();`
Then take a look into it, and here :
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#making-actions-require-authorization

Comment: @AnujTBE and this as well : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuration-options

Comment: if `$this->Auth->user('super_admin')` is being called, then I don't think I need to call `AuthComponent` manually in controller. Because if that was needed then even `$this->Auth->user('super_admin')` will not be executed and exception will be thrown.